# create shortcode function in PHP (search text for shortcodes, replace shortcode with link)

Tags: php, shortcode

I am attempting to create my own shortcodes in PHP on my site (straight PHP, no CMS). I have a large database and would like to add shortcodes to many of the TEXT fields, to make linking and other items easier. I know how to replace text using PHP, but have a complex code that I am trying to implement... Below is an example of some text:

```
$textarea = "a long list of text [item=23] within a large text string<br>And more stuff [item=35]";
```

I am looking to replace [item=###] with `<a href="/item?id=###"> ITEM NUM NAME </a>`
and to get the 'item name,' I would use the ### to query a database.

So, basically, I need to...

1. Find the strings in the text that start with "[item=" and end with "]". And, add them all to an array (i.e. array('[item=23]','[item=34]') ). This I do not know how to do.
2. When I find these string, extract the numbers. (I assume I can just remove the "[item=" characters from the front of the string and remove the "]" from the end of the string. This I can do. Easy enough.
3. For each number, get the item name ... (this is a simple query that I can create a function to do, using the number extracted). This I can do.
4. And THEN replace the [item=###] with the constructed URL (i.e. `<a href="item?id=23">Gumdrop</a>`).  Not sure how to do this for multiple instances, and different item #s.

If anyone can provide some guidance, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php might be an approach that works for you - within the body of the callback you could specify your name lookup function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is There Anyway To Make Custom BBCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343838/is-there-anyway-to-make-custom-bbcode)

Comment: Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111081/php-bbcode-parser

Comment: Program - The first link isn't useful (the answer is: just use third party plugin). That second link may be something to work with though (php-bbcode-parser)

Comment: Program - Nope...  that second link just shows how to replace strings in content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace_callback` with an appropriate pattern, and in the body of the callback function you could replace the id with the name.

For example:

```php
$replacedText = preg_replace_callback('/\[item=([1-9][0-9]*)\]/', function ($matches) {
    $id = $matches[1];

    // insert call to your name lookup function here
    $name = 'name-of-item-' . $id . '-here';

    return '<a href="/item?id=' . $id .'">' . htmlspecialchars($name) . '</a>';

}, $textarea);
```